# unable to read some .wav files using scipy.io.wavread.read()

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to read .wav file using scipy.io.wavread. It reads some file properly.
For some files its giving following error...

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "D:\project\cardiocare-1.0\src\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 121
    warnings.warn("chunk not understood", WavFileWarning)
WavFileWarning: chunk not understood
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\project\cardiocare-1.0\src\ccare\plot.py", line 37, in plot
    input_data = read(p.bitfile)
  File "D:\project\cardiocare-1.0\src\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 119, in read
    data = _read_data_chunk(fid, noc, bits)
  File "D:\project\cardiocare-1.0\src\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 56, in _read_data_chunk
    data = data.reshape(-1,noc)
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Can any one suggest me any solution?

Comment: What version of scipy are you using?

Comment: i m using scipy 0.11.0
i think this is compatible version with python 2.7

Comment: still problem is not sorted out.. i tried with latest version of sicpy. but still the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

I use the below code to read wav files. I know it does not solve your problem, but maybee you could read your wav file with this code and maybe figure out what is wrong?

My experience is, that wav files sometimes contains "strange" things, that must be handled or removed.

Hope it helps you out

Rgds

Cyrex

```
import wave
import struct                     

def wavRead(fileN):
  waveFile = wave.open(fileN, 'r')   
  NbChanels = waveFile.getnchannels()
  data = []
  for x in range(NbChanels):
      data.append([])
  for i in range(0,waveFile.getnframes()):               
      waveData = waveFile.readframes(1)   
      data[i%(NbChanels)].append(int(struct.unpack("<h", waveData)[0]))

  RetAR = []
  BitDebth = waveFile.getsampwidth()*8
  for x in range(NbChanels):
       RetAR.append(np.array(data[x]))
       RetAR[-1] = RetAR[-1]/float(pow(2,(BitDebth-1)))
  fs = waveFile.getframerate()
  return RetAR,fs
```